# Access a ES module variable from a function which use the same name in parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I want to do something like this:

```
let date = null;

export function setDate(date) {
    // Set "date" from module using "date" from function parameters
}
```

Is this even possible? Or am I obliged to choose different names for both variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. What have you done is called [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing), when different scoped variables have the same name.

Take this example:

```js
let x = 10;
{
  let x = 20;

  try {
    let x = x + 30; // error
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }

  console.log(x); // 20
}
console.log(x); // 10
```

The outer scoped variables kept their value because they're not overwritten, you basically have *different variables* that have the *same name*, and you will always reference to the one in the current scope: since the scope is different, *you're not declaring the same variable twice*.

Notice also the error there, you might try to use the other scoped variables for the value of the inner ones, but it won't work: it would be seen as an usage of the current scoped variable before its initialization.

(The code above use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) because it's block-scoped)

It's worth to mention as a side note, that where having variable shadowing it's usually a bad practice, in some language is implemented on purpose since it helps to write more concise code and readable code: it's the case of Rust, for example, that allow local shadowing.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible due to [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). Actually, variable shadowing should be avoided since it can lead to unintended consequences and make the code harder to understand. Just name things clearly.